# Copy editor badge after 2000 reputation?

Tags: discussion, badges

I currently have less than 2000 reputation. When I reach 2K reputation, I will receive the [edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

My question is: right now my edits are being counted for the `Copy Editor` badge; these edits are also reviewed before they are accepted. But after I've earned 2K, there won't be any peer reviews. So will my edits still  be counted and tracked for the `Copy Editor` badge?

Comment: Your question might need to be edited for clarity.

Comment: @Mari-LouA please feel free to edit. or ask me if something is not clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/295232)

Comment: Yes, both approved suggested edits and '>2k edits' count towards the Copy Editor badge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [description of the `Copy Editor` badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor) does not show any evidence that the edits would no longer be counted.

(I have editor privileges an another Stack Exchange site, and my edits are still being counted for the [`Strunk & White` badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), so I assume edits would also be counted for the `Copy Editor` badge.)